# Android No Resource Identifier Found for XLargeScreens

Tags: android, size, screen, manifest, tablet

I would like my Android app to be compatible with as many devices as humanly possible, so naturally I would like to try to make it ready for all of the new incoming tablets.  Unfortunately when I add :

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
```

To my Manifest, it gives me this error :

```
error:No resource identifier found for attribute "xlargeScreens" in package 'android'
```

Now I'm fairly new to all of this yet, but from what I've read this has something to do with my min/target SDK's being too low to support this, being a brand new feature and all.  I did try raising my target SDK up since I thought that wasn't a problem, but that made most of my code "unable to be resolved".  I'm sure that makes sense to those of you that have been around Android a little longer than myself, but what I'm really wondering is if there is a way for me to enable support for "xlargeScreens".

Perhaps there is some other way, or maybe it's not even necessary to have that line to allow it to work with them.  Perhaps because it's a new addition I've had trouble finding anything that answered this for me, so any suggestions would be great.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you raised the build target to 2.3?

Answer (score 12):

This attribute was introduced in API Level 9.
Check this link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge

Comment: you must specify API 9 in `minSdkVersion` or you can set in `targetSdkVersion` ?

Comment: You also need to make sure that the target setting in project.properties is set to 9 or higher... ex: target=android-9

Answer (score 4):

The android manifest tag android:xlargeScreens="true" does not seem to be recognized anymore, but it does not matter if you have layout-xlarge folder.
Also, xlarge is now SDK 11 stuff for honeycomb, so its a whole big new paradigm.

I suggest forgiving google for occasional inconsistencies in a fast moving digital world.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My widget was not listed in a 3.2 tablet device.

These following options were sufficient:

```
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
```